# RadioButton ContentStringFormat not working

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

I have been struggling to get this code below to work. The binding works but the `ContentStringFormat` in the first or `StringFormat` in the second one doesn't seem to work.

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding ClientCode}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} copy"
             IsChecked="{Binding Path= FilterType,
                 Converter={StaticResource EBConverter}, 
                 ConverterParameter={x:Static wordMerge:FilterType.ClientCopy}}" 
             Width="90"/>
```

The above code just returns the binding value say "ABC" but I am expecting "ABC copy"

```
 <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path= FilterType,
                 Converter={StaticResource EBConverter},
                 ConverterParameter={x:Static wordMerge:FilterType.ClientCopy}}" 
              Width="90">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientCode, StringFormat={}{0} copy}"/>
     </RadioButton.Content>
 </RadioButton>
```

The above code not returning any values for binding.

**Updated**
The string copy is not displayed during design time or at runtime in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried with `StringFormat='\{0\} copy'`?

Comment: If the binding works, the XAML works and you're seeing a value show up.   What is your expected result and what are the results you're currently getting?

Comment: @Alberto tried that and no luck

Comment: do you at least see " copy" displayed?

Comment: @NETscape No the text is not displayed

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
StringFormat='{}copy {0}'}"
```

tested

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Str, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}{0} copy'}"/>
```

@Kiru it works for me

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding Path=Str, Mode=OneWay}"  ContentStringFormat='{}{0} copy'/>
<RadioButton>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Str, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}{0} copy'}"/>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: design time error. You can use single or double quotes after a `=`, so thats was the {} is for, to escape the expectation of brackets.  You would have to do '{}{0} copy' which is the same as "{}{0} copy"

Comment: @Blam Thanks, unfortunately this didn't work. I have to create another property which appends the text and then bind the RadioButton to it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it was not working for me was because I defined my own template for `RadioButton`, but did not specify `ContentStringFormat` binding.

```
<TextBlock 
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
    <InlineUIContainer><ContentPresenter ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/></InlineUIContainer>
</TextBlock>
```